# How to write incoming bytes directly to disk in a Servlet request?

Tags: java, servlets, upload, servlet-3.0

I'd like to know if it is possible to write incoming bytes of a HttpServletRequest directly to disk without holding it in memory.

> Note that I don't want to wait the entire request to complete, but handle partial data independently. Like chunks.

I'm curently using JBOSS and I get these bytes at ServletInputStream in doPost method only after the entire upload completes. But I want to "read and remove" these bytes from InputStream as I read it. There are huge files being uploaded and I'd like to work in a coordinated flow as shown below:

1. 1024 bytes arrived in InputStream
2. 1024 bytes read(and removed) from InputStream
3. 1024 bytes wrote to Outputstream(in this case a FileOutputStream)

Is that possible? To work as a raw socket communication... And thus completely avoid OOM.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `Files.copy(request.getInputStream(), path)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the data partially by using a chunk (buffer) of the desired size:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(yourInputStream);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(yourFileOutputStream);
final int FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4; //easier to change to 8 KBs or any other size you want/need
byte[] chunk = new byte[FILE_CHUNK_SIZE];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(chunk)) != -1) {
    bos.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
}
bos.close();
bis.close();
```

Comment: Luiggi thanks for the answer. That is a good way to solve another problem, not exactly mine.
To be more clear, it's much more a JEE chalenge than a JSE.
The 'doPost' which holds the inputstream, is called once upload is completed. But it is not what I want.
I want to read bytes in chunks, as you said, while upload is working.

Comment: Then please provide the relevant elements to replicate your scenario, otherwise your question is unclear and should be closed.

Comment: Ops, I didnt mean to send my consideration like that. Edited.

Comment: Ok, please be more specific: read bytes from where and write it where? Or are you saying that you have a code like this but still gives you OOM (which will be very strange because I've sent 4 GB files using this approach and the server doesn't die).

Comment: Well, is your servlet able to start reading ServletInputStream before the upload is entire complete? Maybe I'm wrong, but 'doPost' is called once everything is on server side. And that is exactly what I'd like to avoid. I dont wanna have the entire file loaded in InputStream before reading. I want to read each chunk of bytes as soon as they reach container(Jboss). And I think doPost is not the right choice, for that. For the reason I mentioned.
Am I Wrong?
Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. There's no way using Servlets where you can start reading the bytes written in the wire before your web app reads them, build the parameters and give it to you. Probably you should use websockets for the job as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21769470/1065197)