# Is it possible to send file through actioncable ? If possible, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I already implemented the chat function using actioncable but don't know how to send file through it or is it even possible or not.
I am trying to make chat application where user can upload file in chatroom other users can see that immediately without reloading the page as actioncable offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to upload files using websockets. ([File upload using java websocket API and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769470/file-upload-using-java-websocket-api-and-javascript))

But through ActionCable that's not possible at the moment. As ActionCable wraps the Websocket in Javascript this is also going to be "hacky" to patch this in, so I would wait for a new release and write an issue on the rails repo instead.

So for your chat app you still need to use a normal form submit to upload a file. If you want it to happen asynchronously you can use my "patched" version of jquery-ujs which allows sending files with the "data-remote=true" flag.
See https://github.com/Elektron1c97/jquery-ujs-files

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by transforming your file into a base64 data url on the client via some js then to send this url thru actioncable to the server who's gonna broadcast just a base64 data url.

I have test it with image, audio and video files. Not with pdf or txt but it should work. For big file like a video it's instable.

It's just experimental.

Voilà.